Equation of line passing (1,4) having minimum sum of intercept on positive axis?
We have to find Equation of straight line passing through $(1,4)$ having minimum sum of intercept on positive axis?
So I have two approaches:
Method 1
First $a+b$ ($a$ and $b$ are intercept on positive $x$ and $y$ axis) to be min , by AM/GM inequality I can say it is minimum when $a=b$.
Equation of line
$\frac{x}{a} + \frac{y}{b}=1$
Will satisfy $(1,4)$ and $a=b$ so I get $a=b=5$
Method 2
Writing equation of line letting slope $m$ then write intercept in form of $m$; get expression of their sum then differentiating with with respect to slope or using am gm given that $m$ is negative.
Method 2 gives correct answer but why method 1 gives wrong answer is it to do with the line equation because before assuming $a=b$?  I didn't think that it should pass through $(1,4)$?

Minimizing $a+b$ subject to the constraint of keeping $ab$ constant happens when $a=b$, but you don't have that $ab$ is constant, what you have is that $(1/a)+(4/b)=1$, so there is no reason to think $a=b$.

The minimum sum of the interceptions is when the straight line passes through the origin, because then both interceptions are zero.

@R.J, the question specified intercepts on the positive axis.The origin doesn't qualify.

A straight line $y=ax+b$ passing through $(x,y)=(1,4)$ induces
$4=a+b$. Interceptions are at $y=0$, which gives $x_i=-b/a$,
and at $x=0$, which gives $y_i=b$. Arithmetic sum of signed (!) interceptions
is $S = -b/a+b$, with dependence above, same as $S=(a-1)(4-a)/a$.
First derivative is $S'= -(a-2)(a+2)/a^2$. Setting this to zero yields $a=2$ or $-2$ for a local maximum of $S(a)$ at $S=1$ and a local minum $S=9$. The global minimum $S=-\infty$ is with $a\rightarrow +0$ as a graphic representation of $S(a)$ reveals.
